# Ionic 2 Erro na hora de gerar o build para o android no windows 10

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugin

```
$ ionic build android
> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build C:\Users\Gustavo\Documents\Ionic2\like_you
> ionic-app-scripts build

[20:16:23]  ionic-app-scripts 1.3.0
[20:16:23]  build dev started ...
[20:16:23]  clean started ...
[20:16:23]  clean finished in less than 1 ms
[20:16:23]  copy started ...
[20:16:23]  transpile started ...
[20:16:27]  transpile finished in 3.64 s
[20:16:27]  preprocess started ...
[20:16:27]  deeplinks started ...
[20:16:27]  deeplinks finished in 31 ms
[20:16:27]  preprocess finished in 31 ms
[20:16:27]  webpack started ...
[20:16:27]  copy finished in 3.98 s
[20:16:36]  webpack finished in 9.48 s
[20:16:36]  sass started ...
[20:16:38]  sass finished in 1.09 s
[20:16:38]  postprocess started ...
[20:16:38]  postprocess finished in 62 ms
[20:16:38]  lint started ...
[20:16:38]  build dev finished in 14.36 s
[20:16:40]  lint finished in 2.30 s
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper
bash: $: command not found
```

Eu instalei o android studio normal e só que ele fala pra atualizar o SDK mas o android studio fala que já está atualizado e o a pasta templates\gradpe\wrapper não existe.